# How to pass hiddenfield value to another page in asp.net?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, vb.net

I have 3 tabs on master page. When I am clicking on "abc" tab ,here I am setting  value in hidden field like this:

```
    $(".menuitem_categorytype_link1").click(function(){

                $("#<%= producttab.ClientID%>").val("123");
                alert($("#producttab").val());
               });
   <li class="toplink item twoline">
        <a title="" id="prdtoptab"  href="Products.aspx"  class="menuitem_categorytype_link1">Products</a>
   </li>
```

I am able to set value in hidden field, But now I want to use this hiddenfield value on product.aspx  page code behind  to do something like this:

```
if (hdnfield.value=123)

{
   //select product etc

 }
```

I tried to get hiddenfield value on master page_load event and then tried to pass value in session but I am not able to get hiddenfield value on master page_load event.

Please let me know what I am doing wrong and how I can use this hiddenfield on another page?

Thanks.

Comment: Why you need to get hidden field value on master page when you can add in session simply from the code behind of a page where this is being used?

Answer (score 0):

make it a server control hiddenfield. Set the PostbackUrl property of the button to the next page and retrieve the information there.

For a good example on how to use the PostBackUrl property take a look at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.button.postbackurl.aspx.

Comment: using already server control hidden field.able to set  value in jquery but not on code behind.issue creates only  because of this   <a title="" id="prdtoptab"  href="Products.aspx"  class="menuitem_categorytype_link1">Products</a>